# Errors in fragment class

Tags: java, android, eclipse, class, android-fragments

So I am converting my application, after loads of research I decided to convert my Activities into Fragments. That was a success, but now the slightly harder part comes in, to implement the code from my Activity to the fragments. So I used getView(). and getActivity(). to fix the issues, and all was fine. As you can see below...

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {  

  public static HomeFragment newInstance(String title) {

      HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
      Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
      bundle.putString("title", title);
      homeFragment.setArguments(bundle);
      return homeFragment;
  }

  @Override  
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
  }  

  @Override  
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {          
      View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_activity_home, container, false);  

        // Time function - Displays timeview on Card
        final boolean keepRunning = true;
        Thread thread = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run(){

                while(keepRunning){

                    // Make the thread wait half a second (if you're only showing time up to seconds, it doesn't need to be updating constantly)
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Default Signature Fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                        @Override
                        public void run(){
                            TextView time = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.time);
                            time.setText(DateUtils.formatDateTime(getActivity().getBaseContext(), System.currentTimeMillis(),DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME | DateUtils.FORMAT_12HOUR));
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        };

        thread.start();

        // Date function - Displays dateview on Card
        final boolean keepRunning1 = true;
        Thread thread_two = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run(){

                while(keepRunning1){

                    // Make the thread wait half a second. If you want...
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Default Signature Fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                        @Override
                        public void run(){
                            TextView date = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.date);
                            date.setText(DateUtils.formatDateTime(getActivity().getBaseContext(), System.currentTimeMillis(),DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_WEEKDAY | DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_DATE | DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_YEAR));
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        };

        thread_two.start();
      return view;  
    }  
}
```

When running the application, it displays the app for approx 2 secs and then force closes, so I checked the logs for any errors. And this came up --

```
05-20 16:54:17.213: E/AndroidRuntime(26473): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
05-20 16:54:17.213: E/AndroidRuntime(26473):    at com.activelauncher.fragments.HomeFragment$1$1.run(HomeFragment.java:54)
```

I'm fairly new to Fragments I have had more experience working with Activities so I don't know what the issue is here. So I check line 54 and it was this line --

```
time.setText(DateUtils.formatDateTime(getActivity().getBaseContext(), System.currentTimeMillis(),DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME | DateUtils.FORMAT_12HOUR));
```

However I don't see any issues or errors there? Is there something I am missing?
Thanks for reading this.

Comment: you are using threads to create a dealy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
TextView time = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.time);
```

to

```
TextView time = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.time);
```

And make this final

```
final View view;
```

Simailarly

```
TextView date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);
```

Comment: @Robin `getView()` returns null. You can initialze views in `onActivityCreated` using `getView()`. You need to wait till fragment is attached to the activity

Comment: @Robin fix the time first then run again see if you get NPE @ date. I guess you will. Also to create a delay you can use a Handler isntead of a Thread

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Change this..

```
TextView time = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.time);
time.setText(DateUtils.formatDateTime(getActivity().getBaseContext(), System.currentTimeMillis(),DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME | DateUtils.FORMAT_12HOUR));
```

to

```
TextView time = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.time);
time.setText(""+DateUtils.formatDateTime(getActivity().getBaseContext(), System.currentTimeMillis(),DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME | DateUtils.FORMAT_12HOUR));
```

and also

```
TextView date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);
date.setText(""+DateUtils.formatDateTime(getActivity().getBaseContext(), System.currentTimeMillis(),DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_WEEKDAY | DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_DATE | DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_YEAR));
```